# How to rotate the zoom control on a mapview to vertical in android

Tags: android, google-maps, android-mapview

I have a map, in that map i have placed a zoomcontrol like this

```
    View zoomView = mapView.getZoomControls(); 
    zoomLayout.addView(zoomView, new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)); 
    mapView.displayZoomControls(true);
```

In xml it is used like this

```
<LinearLayout 
    android:id="@+id/layout_zoom"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" 
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"/> 
</LinearLayout>
```

Now i need to rotate this zoom in vertical format... how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best thing to do is create a vertical linear layout with 2 image button elements(one for zoom in and one for zoom out), you will have to create your own images if you want them to look like the android ones, then just call mapView.getController().zoomIn() or zoomOut().

Answer (score 0):

With the new API you can zoom controlling the camera:

```
googleMap.animateCamera(
    CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(
    cluster.getPosition(), 
    (float) Math.floor(googleMap.getCameraPosition().zoom + 1)), 
    300, 
   null);
```